# Failing to connect to compojure-app with LightTable

Tags: clojure, leiningen, lighttable

I just ran "lein new compojure-app guestbook" following the book "Web Development with Clojure". In one step the book is connecting to my Clojure project with light table. However when I try this I get the following error that makes no sense to me.

[Here is the error I'm getting](http://lpaste.net/110075)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

### Your Error

For the search engines, here is a copy of the pertinent part of your error:

```
Error loading lighttable.nrepl.handler: java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to resolve var: reader/*alias-map* in this context
```

### The Cause

Lighttable has upgraded to using a newer `tools.reader`.

I found two resources:

1. An applicable [github issue](https://github.com/LightTable/LightTable/issues/1401) that you might find helpful.
2. A [forum thread](http://forums.pragprog.com/forums/308/topics/12552) covering the question (mentioned in the github issue above).

### The Summarized Solution

Several people have solved this by simply running `lein clean` in their project directory.

If `lein clean` does not solve it for you, then here is the extended solution from the forum:

> In project.clj. Replace
>
> [compojure “1.1.6”]
>
> with
>
> [compojure “1.1.6” :exclusions [org.clojure/tools.reader]]
>
> and add to the :dependencies list
>
> [org.clojure/tools.reader “0.7.10”]
>
> The reason seems to be that LightTable expects this version of
>   tools.reader, but Compojure brings in version 0.7.3

After employing this solution, you may wish to run `lein clean` again.

Comment: I only had to run lein clean